# Form with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm creating a Form with UITableView, I want that when i click over any part of my row, get the focus on the textfield so I can write on it. Right now to focus on the textfield (yellow space) i have to click only over the textfield (see image). Name is the title (not editable)  [image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have a textField named `myTextField` that you want to have focused when selecting the first row in the table.

Do this in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of the row, call `[correspondingTextField becomeFirstResponder]`;

Answer (score 0):

You can make the textbox as "becomefirstreponder" in didselectrow in case you have it in a table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your delegate properly, this is  the  delegate method which is fired when user click over any rows. 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

So, in this method you are going to use becomeFirstResponder method to get the focus.

`[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder ];`